# Paypal procedures / processes in registering a new IP address for site migration?

Tags: paypal

Paypal linked to Stackoverflow for developer support so here goes my question.

Our site is using Paypal Express Checkout and Paypal Payments Advanced. We will be migrating our site to a new server soon and a new IP address will be provided for the site.

Does Paypal have any procedures / processes in registering a new IP address? (or do we even need to register the new IP address?)

I want to avoid issues when the site interacts with Paypal as the DNS propagates the new IP address. We want to avoid the issue of Paypal invalidating our site since its IP address suddenly changed in the middle of a transaction.

Answer (score 0):

Talked with Paypal over the phone and they said there's no issue to be concerned with unless you set in your Paypal Manager account to restrict the IP address that is doing the API calls.

If you did some restriction, then you would just have to add in there the new IP address.